# Where am I screwing up in the evaluation of this mathematical expression in Java?

Tags: java, expression

My Code is:

```
int x=5,y=3;
x+=y*++x-x/y-y++;
System.out.println("Value = "+x);
```

My evaluation is as below:

> x+=y*++x-x/y-y++
> (x=5 | y=3)
>
> x=x+(y*++x-x/y-y++)
> (x=5 | y=3) | ++ and -- have highest priority
>
> x=x+(y*6-x/y-3)
> (x=6 | y=4) | * and / have next highest priority
>
> x=x+(4*6-(6/4)-3)
> (x=6 | y=4)
>
> x=x+(24 -1 -3)
> (x=6 | y=4)
>
> x= 6+20
> (x=6 | y=4)
>
> x = 26.

However, when I evaluate the above in Java, the output turns out to be 18. What did I do wrong?

Additionally, is there any program online that can solve such problems as above with step by step analysis? If so, could you name some?

Comment: Expressions like `x+=y*++x-x/y-y++` are *exactly* why people avoid them. You'll be a much better developer if you avoid them as well. And we won't have to track you down to punish you :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo It was school homework for one of my students.. :'(

Comment: The mistake you made was executing the post-increment during the expression, when it should be left until after the expression is calculated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The expression is evaluated from left to right :

```
x += (y*++x)-(x/y) -(y++);
      3*6   - 6/3  - 3     == 18 - 2 - 3 == 13
```

so

```
x += 13 == 18 // since the original value of x is used here
```

Regarding the last part, the original value of `x` is used since that's the definition of [compound assignment operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2) :

> - First, the left-hand operand is evaluated to produce a variable. If this evaluation completes abruptly, then the assignment expression
>     completes abruptly for the same reason; the right-hand operand is not
>     evaluated and no assignment occurs.
> - Otherwise, **the value of the left-hand operand is saved and then the right-hand operand is evaluated**. If this evaluation completes
>     abruptly, then the assignment expression completes abruptly for the
>     same reason and no assignment occurs.
> - Otherwise, **the saved value of the left-hand variable** and the value of the right-hand operand are used to perform the binary operation
>     indicated by the compound assignment operator. If this operation
>     completes abruptly, then the assignment expression completes abruptly
>     for the same reason and no assignment occurs.
> - Otherwise, the result of the binary operation is converted to the type of the left-hand variable, subjected to value set conversion
>     (§5.1.13) to the appropriate standard value set (not an
>     extended-exponent value set), and the result of the conversion is
>     stored into the variable.

Comment: why is the original value of x=5 used even though the value of x=6 is used throughout the rest of the expression?

Comment: also, aren't ++x, --x, ++y and --y supposed to be calculated before all other expressions? why aren't we doing that here? Ref: http://www.cs.bilkent.edu.tr/~guvenir/courses/CS101/op_precedence.html

Comment: @SomenathSinha Added JLS reference to explain your first comment's question.

Comment: @SomenathSinha Regarding the second comment, the JLS states that `The left-hand operand of a binary operator appears to be fully evaluated before any part of the right-hand operand is evaluated.` So, for example, for the `*` operator, `y` is evaluated before `x++` and for the second `-` operator, `(y*++x)-(x/y)` is evaluated before `y++`.

Comment: thanks Mr.Eran for your efforts , i got confused with the precedence level but @KevinEsche clear my doubts with example plus i apologize if i sounded rude in any way.i hope for peace